# Foreach loop to see the whole loop before it executes

Tags: php, loops

I have this code:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['protiens']['thur'] as $key => $meal)
{
    if($_SESSION['protiens']['thur'][$key]['qty'] == 0)
        {
          echo " none";
        }

}
```

It is suppose to hide the days if their qty is empty, but right now it takes weather it was chosen last, if I didn't chose a meal for Friday and I chose for Monday and Wednesday, Friday is not shown, how can I make it that if Friday has any qty for it to show, no matter whenever it was chosen? [image]

Comment: Could you clarify this part of the question "*if I didn't chose a meal for friday and I chose for monday and wednesday, friday is not shown, how can I make it that if Friday has any qty for it to show, no matter whenever it was*". It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Right now it shows monday & wednesday, if I add a meal (final meal) for monday ONLY, the word "Wednesday " will not display since the last foreach in the loop will be zero so echo "none" will show and wednesday will be display none, how can I fix that? @AmalMurali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming you have an array partly like:

```
$days = [
    'Mon' => ['qty' => 0],
    'Tue' => ['qty' => 0],
    'Wed' => ['qty' => 0],
    'Thu' => ['qty' => 1],
    'Fri' => ['qty' => 0],
    'Sat' => ['qty' => 0],
    'Sun' => ['qty' => 0],
];
```

And you want the sum of all `qty` values you can use a combination of [array_column](http://php.net/manual/function.array-column.php) and [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/function.array-sum.php) like:

```
if (array_sum(array_column($days, 'qty'))) {
    // foreach display the items
} else {
    echo 'None';
}
```

Or an old fashioned counter like:

```
$mealCount = 0;
foreach ($days as $meal) {
    $mealCount += $meal['qty'];
}

if ($mealCount) {
    // foreach display the items
} else {
    echo 'None';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctrly, you want to skip to next value in case quantity is zero.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['protiens']['thur'] as $key => $meal)
{
    if($meal['qty'] == 0)
        {
          continue;
        }

}
```

Comment: I want that if it has no meals at all for it to hide which is echo "none"

Comment: continue will jump to next iteration ignoring the code below, thus serving "hide" purpose, however if you want echo 'Hide' before that you can do it.